# What datatype to be used for limiting the input length?

Tags: sql, rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

I have an ontology which is written by taking SQL table as input. The SQL table has the column 'EquipmentCategoryName' which uses datatype nvarchar(10). How can I define this constraint datatype in the ontology?
So far I have written the following statement in my ontology:

```
:EquipmentCategoryName a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:domain :EquipmentCategory ;
        rdfs:range xsd:string .
```

Can I limit the string length? If yes, What statement I need to be written?

Comment: The only way in OWL is to use [facets](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-quick-reference/#Facets)

Comment: `:EquipmentCategoryName rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
                       rdfs:domain :EquipmentCategory ;
                       rdfs:range [ rdf:type rdfs:Datatype ;
                                    owl:onDatatype xsd:string ;
                                    owl:withRestrictions ( [ xsd:maxLength "10"^^xsd:int
                                                           ]
                                                         )
                                  ] .`